# C++: Error when copying from *std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, valgrind, shared-ptr

I have a function that returns a shared pointer to an object (it is difficult to include the MyObject definition because of many large dependencies):

```
std::shared_ptr<MyObject> f(std::string params)
{
  return std::shared_ptr<MyObject>(new MyObject(params));
}
```

Does anyone know why this code works:

**Case 1: no errors with `valgrind -v --tool=memcheck`**

```
std::shared_ptr<MyObject> obj_ptr = f("hello");
MyObject obj = *obj_ptr;
```

While this code crashes:

**Case 2: crashes and gives several errors with `valgrind -v --tool=memcheck`**

```
MyObject obj = *f("hello");
```

The MyObject class has a working assignment operator and copy constructor (both verified in **Case 1**).

I have also tried creating a `std::shared_ptr<MyObject>` (via `f`), copying that to a pointer, copying the pointer to an object on the stack, and deleting the pointer. The final object on the stack is still fine:

**Case 3: no errors with `valgrind -v --tool=memcheck`**

```
std::shared_ptr<MyObject> obj_ptr = f("hello");
MyObject * obj_ptr2 = new MyObject(*obj_ptr);
MyObject obj3 = *obj_ptr2;
delete obj_ptr2;
obj3.print();
```

Is the error perhaps because `std::shared_ptr` is created as an rvalue, and frees its memory as soon as the `*` operator runs?

Comment: What version of what compiler are you using?

Comment: And what is the error when it crashes? A stack trace might help...

Comment: Is MyObject copy constructor doing a deep copy? (Case 1 would still work fine with shallow copy).

Comment: @bobah Yes. If not, **Case 3** would fail.

Comment: Please just humor us with the definition of MyObject.

Comment: Examples 1 and 3 do nothing "odd". Example 2 dereferences a smart pointer that will be deleted right away(or has just been deleted).

Comment: @fontanini : It will be deleted at the end of the full expression, but that is not (or should not be) a problem here.

Comment: @fontanini Correct. Is this misuse of shared_ptr? Normally I would assume that my MyObject class has memory problems, but then wouldn't valgrind find some problem in **Case 1** or **Case 3**?

Comment: @Oliver: Only if you trust valgrind.  I've never used it, so I don't.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley valgrind does complain reading invalid memory (during copy construction) in **Case 2** only. The code necessary to run is in a handful of files-- should I put a zip of it somewhere?

Comment: What happens when a non-shared pointer, such as unique_ptr, is used?

Comment: @damienh I just tried unique_ptr: same outcome for **Case 2**.

Comment: It's nearly certain that the bug is in your copy constructor.

Comment: @Oliver: And what happens if you replace `MyObject` with a well tested class that manages memory, like `std::string`?

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley I too once did not trust valgrind's results saying I was leaking memory, and spent a few days debugging in other ways. I finally found the problem and it turned out valgrind was 100% spot on at the very beginning. I've been a believer ever since.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Just tried with `vector<string>`, and it worked fine, so I guess the answer (below) is onto something... But I am shocked that valgrind would miss it.

Comment: @Oliver: If Mark B's answer is correct, then valgrind isn't missing anything.

Comment: @Oliver You said in the second case it *does* find a problem. `valgrind` isn't magic: If you don't execute the bad code it can't find the problem (and as I explain in my answer, the bad code almost certainly isn't being executed in those two cases).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is (almost certainly) that you're shallow-copying one of the members of `MyObject` in its copy constructor. Then you either try to access the shallow data that's no longer valid, or you double delete it.

Consider the cases:
In the first and third cases, the very first object from which all copies are made is still alive when you act on the stack object. In the second case the `shared_ptr` goes away after the copy construction, invoking the destructor of `MyObject`.

If you changed the third case thusly, I suspect it would crash:

```
MyObject * obj_ptr2 = new MyObject("hello");
MyObject obj3 = *obj_ptr2;
delete obj_ptr2;
obj3.print();
```

Comment: +1 I think you're right-- I actually have callable destructors (`clear()`). I tried **Case 3** again, but destructed the original object after it was copied, and got an error.

Comment: It turned out I was doing a shallow copy somewhere. Thanks.